# JMF: Setting FPS for webcam

Tags: java, webcam, jmf

I have a webcam (actually 3) and java program to capture the frames. However, I have yet to find a way to set the FPS. For example, when I'm setting the FPS using a new `VideoFormat` and I can see that it is correctly applied by `camFormat.intersects(newFormat)`. However, when I get frames from the camera (either by the `BufferTransferHandler` or by manually fetching), I get more frames than the selected FPS.

Is there perhaps a way to poll if a new frame is ready?

**I found a little more information, so I'm editing this.
It seems the source of the problems is the Microsoft WDM Image Capture driver. In VirtualDub capture mode, I can select each separate webcam and I can select WDM. When I select WDM, I get the same options as in the *Custom Format* dialog in JFM, and it doesn't capture at full FPS either. However,** `CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList` **seems to only return the WDM driver and not the individual webcams (and two microphones inside webcams but not the sound card microphone). Why is this?**

It strikes me odd that I can specify the framerate, but I can't find a way to actually enforce it, even after days of searching the internet and trying different example code. Every example I find will just either request frames at its own pace or not care about fps at all.

My test class:

Run, use the top button to (re)open the Format Control window (internal to JMF), and try to change the fps. It's also odd that besides the non-functional fps field, other fields like the resolution field are also non-functional (as it is overridden by the resolution field in the "Custom Format..."  window.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.media.Buffer;
import javax.media.CaptureDeviceInfo;
import javax.media.CaptureDeviceManager;
import javax.media.ControllerAdapter;
import javax.media.ControllerClosedEvent;
import javax.media.ControllerErrorEvent;
import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.MediaLocator;
import javax.media.Player;
import javax.media.RealizeCompleteEvent;
import javax.media.StartEvent;
import javax.media.StopEvent;
import javax.media.control.FormatControl;
import javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl;
import javax.media.format.FormatChangeEvent;
import javax.media.format.VideoFormat;
import javax.media.format.YUVFormat;
import javax.media.util.BufferToImage;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CaptureTest extends JComponent implements ActionListener, WindowListener, Runnable
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Runnable r = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new CaptureTest();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(r);
    }

    Player                  player;
    FrameGrabbingControl    grabber;
    FormatControl           formatControl;
    final JFrame            frame;
    public Image            image;

    public CaptureTest()
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        Vector<?> deviceVector = CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList(new YUVFormat());

        final CaptureDeviceInfo[] deviceList = new CaptureDeviceInfo[deviceVector.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < deviceList.length; i++)
        {
            deviceList[i] = (CaptureDeviceInfo)deviceVector.get(i);
            System.out.println("Capture Device found: " + deviceList[i].getName());
        }

        frame = new JFrame("Capture test");
        frame.addWindowListener(this);

        {
            JButton b = new JButton("Format Control");
            b.setEnabled(true);
            b.addActionListener(this);

            frame.add(b, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        }
        {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
            frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }

        ControllerAdapter cl = new ControllerAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void realizeComplete(RealizeCompleteEvent rce)
            {
                formatControl = (FormatControl)player.getControl("javax.media.control.FormatControl");
                grabber = (FrameGrabbingControl)player.getControl("javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl");

                Component co = formatControl.getControlComponent();
                if (co != null)
                {
                    player.stop();
                    JDialog d = new JDialog(frame, "Format Control", true);
                    d.add(co);
                    d.pack();
                    d.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
                    d.setVisible(true);
                    d.dispose();
                    player.start();
                }

                System.out.println("realizeComplete: " + formatControl.getFormat());
            }

            @Override
            public void formatChange(FormatChangeEvent fce)
            {}

            @Override
            public void start(StartEvent se)
            {}

            @Override
            public void stop(StopEvent se)
            {}

            @Override
            public void controllerError(ControllerErrorEvent cee)
            {
                System.err.println(cee.getMessage());
                System.err.println("Caused by: " + cee.getSource());
                System.exit(0);
            }

            @Override
            public void controllerClosed(ControllerClosedEvent cce)
            {}
        };

        MediaLocator ml = deviceList[0].getLocator();
        try
        {
            Manager.setHint(Manager.PLUGIN_PLAYER, Boolean.TRUE);
            player = Manager.createPlayer(ml);
            player.addControllerListener(cl);
            player.start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Could Not Create Player", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void grab()
    {
        if (grabber == null)
            return;

        Buffer buf = grabber.grabFrame();
        // System.out.println(fps.getFPS() + "\t" + buf.getFormat());
        BufferToImage b2i = new BufferToImage((VideoFormat)buf.getFormat());
        BufferedImage bi = (BufferedImage)b2i.createImage(buf);
        if (bi != null)
        {
            setImage(bi);
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void setImage(Image im)
    {
        image = im;
        Dimension size = new Dimension(im.getWidth(null), im.getHeight(null));

        setPreferredSize(size);
        setSize(size);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        if (image != null)
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            grab();
            Thread.yield();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Component co = formatControl.getControlComponent();
        if (co != null)
        {
            player.stop();
            JDialog d = new JDialog(frame, "Format Control", true);
            d.add(co);
            d.pack();
            d.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
            d.setVisible(true);
            d.dispose();
            player.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e)
    {}

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
    {
        if (player != null)
        {
            player.stop();
            player.close();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e)
    {}

    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e)
    {}

    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e)
    {}

    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e)
    {}

    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e)
    {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a DirectShow to Java wrapper replacement for JMF (http://www.humatic.de/htools/dsj.htm) which is a lot slower, but does the job.

Comment: You're probably right. JMF has not been updated/released since 2003 and I was not able to detect my webcam on a 64 bits Linux (only 32 bits libraries available) !